# Variables names :type and @type stafe to use in a Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am making changes to an existing Ruby on Rails 3 application that I am also going to upgrade to Rails 4.

It uses the variables `:type` and `@type` a number of times.  Even though "type" is not a reserved Ruby keyword, does naming a variable in Ruby on Rails `type` cause any problems?

Comment: where a you used `@type` or `:type`? Where is the problem?

Comment: `:type` is not a variable.

Comment: http://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Not really. The only place where you'll likely need some configuration to be able to use the `type` name is on models - if you have a column called `type` on your database, Rails will interpret that as the inheritance column for [STI (single-table inheritance)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Single+table+inheritance) unless you configure it not to.

Answer (score 0):

### Variables

Using a variable with name `type` is **no problem** (you can even name your variable `attr`).

### Database columns

Be careful not to create a *database column* called `type`—Active Record uses this name by default to implement single table inheritance (there are some other significant column names listed in the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#schema-conventions)), though it [can be changed](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Single+table+inheritance):

> Active Record allows inheritance by storing the name of the
>   class in a column that by default is named “type”
>   (can be changed by overwriting `Base.inheritance_column`).

---

*N.B.* `:type` is not a variable, it's an instance of the [Symbol class](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Symbol.html) (just as `1` is an instance of [Fixnum](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Fixnum.html)).